# bootstrap 3.3.7 tooltip is not showing properly in angular 4 app

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an Angular 4.2 project and implementing bootstrap 3.3.7 tooltip but my tooltip shows as plain text and not like "bootstrap" tooltip. I have installed Jquery and bootstrap ( it does have tooltip.js as well). I am importing bootstrap css and js file in the angular-cli.json as well. But somehow the tooltip is not showing properly.
  I tried executing below line of code,
    `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

and it worked as expected.
Following is my **angular-cli.json** file

```
` "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],`
```

My question is:  Why Angular is ignoring bootstrap **tooltip.js** file. Although when I check the **vendor.bundle.js** file, I do see the **tooltip.js** file been downloaded. Why I need to call the tooltip() function explicitly to get the bootstrap tooltip??

Comment: You can take a look at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), an Angular implementation of Bootstrap.

Comment: @ ConnorsFan  currently, I am using  bootstrap 3.3.7 so do we have the ng-bootstrap for this version??  I googled it quickly and found-out that I need to install one more npm package **ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3** to use ng-bootstrap with bootstrap 3.3.7.  Do we have any other way around?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that it supported only Boostrap 4. You may try [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started) then.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, thanks for your inputs. yeah, we are planning to migrate to bootstrap 4 in coming months. once we are done with it. I will try ng-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that issue. The issue was with bootstrap as it needs jquery to be GLOBAL. So I am good now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to Angular, but to Bootstrap itself:

> For performance reasons, the Tooltip and Popover data-apis are opt-in,
>   meaning you must initialize them yourself.

More info [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips) under "Opt-in functionality".

Comment: ohh..I see. but I tried adding **(<any>$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')).tooltip();** in the ngAfterViewInit  event and still it does not show properly. If I try to do the same in the google chrome console, tooltip shows properly. any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out that issue. The issue was with bootstrap as it needs jquery to be global. So I am good now.  Thanks for your inputs.